# php regex find string if other string is found n lines before

Tags: php, regex

i'm trying to get every audio and subtitles language from mkvinfo output into array, i've tried various search on google and regex combination on RegExr with no luck. My source string is

```
| + Muxing application: libmkv 0.6.5
| + Writing application: HandBrake rev5474
| + Timecode scale: 1000000
| + Duration: 6788.031s (01:53:08.031)
|+ Segment tracks
| + A track
|  + Track number: 1 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 0)
|  + Track UID: 718870071
|  + Track type: video
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
|  + CodecPrivate, length 45 (h.264 profile: High @L3.1)
|  + Default duration: 41.708ms (23.976 frames/fields per second for a video track)
|  + Default flag: 1
|  + MinCache: 1
|  + Video track
|   + Pixel width: 1280
|   + Pixel height: 536
|   + Display width: 1280
|   + Display height: 536
| + A track
|  + Track number: 2 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 1)
|  + Track UID: 1000053498
|  + Track type: audio
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: A_AAC
|  + CodecPrivate, length 2
|  + Language: fre
|  + Default flag: 1
|  + Audio track
|   + Sampling frequency: 48000
|   + Channels: 2
| + A track
|  + Track number: 3 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 2)
|  + Track UID: 1097600287
|  + Track type: audio
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: A_AAC
|  + CodecPrivate, length 2
|  + Language: eng
|  + Default flag: 0
|  + Audio track
|   + Sampling frequency: 48000
|   + Channels: 2
| + A track
|  + Track number: 4 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 3)
|  + Track UID: 1976675274
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_TEXT/UTF8
|  + Language: fre
|  + Default flag: 0
| + A track
|  + Track number: 5 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 4)
|  + Track UID: 1930079859
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + Codec ID: S_TEXT/UTF8
|  + Language: fre
|  + Default flag: 0
|+ Cluster
```

with regex `Language:\s([a-z]+)` i can get all audio and subtitles

```
Language: fre
Language: eng
Language: fre
Language: fre
```

ideal output would be

```
Array
(
    [audio] => Array
        (
            [0] => eng
            [1] => fre
        )

    [subtitles] => Array
        (
            [0] => fre
            [1] => fre
        )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance,
Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an alternation to match either of the values in 2 capturing groups and have the dot match a newline using `(?s)`

Then you could for example assemble the result array using group 1 for the key and add the value of group 2 to the group 1 key.

```
(?s)\+\h+Track type:\h+(audio|subtitles)\b.*?\+\h+Language:\h+([a-z]+)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QOvexJ/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/ujOtr)

For example

```
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$result = [];

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $result[$match[1]][] = $match[2];
}

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [audio] => Array
        (
            [0] => fre
            [1] => eng
        )

    [subtitles] => Array
        (
            [0] => fre
            [1] => fre
        )

)
```

A bit more precise pattern which does not require the `(?s)` could be matching the `Track type:` and match all lines that do not start with either A track or Language:

```
^\|\h+\+\h+Track type:\h+(audio|subtitles)(?:\R(?!\|\h+\+\h+(?:[A-Z] track$|Language:)).*)*\R\|\h+\+ Language:\h+([a-z]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rfz6yr/1)

Comment: thank you so much for your help, it put an end to three hours of search